# which items are being referred to by Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

My Code below.
I am trying to get data about P&G, Microsoft, Ford and General Electic.
I am getting the valueError when getting into the loop. 
please assit

````
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
***pointers to the data required***
tickers = ['PG', 'MSFT', 'F', 'GE']
mydata = pd.DataFrame()
for t in tickers:
    ***error seems to be occuring here***
    mydata[t] = wb.DataReader(t, data_source='yahoo', start='2019-1-1')
<the code does not get to this part>***emphasized text***
print(mydata.info())```


[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFFwZ.png
````

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
from pandas_datareader import data, wb
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1)
tickers = ['PG', 'MSFT', 'F', 'GE']
df = data.DataReader(tickers,'yahoo', start, end)
df
```